# np.transpose doesn't return transpose of matrix

Tags: python, numpy

When I write my code in the following manner :

```
from numpy import *
H = array([1,1])
Ht = transpose(H)
Ht
```

I get the same matrix as H instead of the transpose of H.

But when I change the matrix H in the following way :

```
from numpy import *
H = array(([1,1],[2,3]))
Ht = transpose(H)
Ht
```

I get the transpose of H.

I fail to understand what is happening here. Is it the way transpose function is used or is it the way a matrix is defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is the behavior you're looking for:

```
>>> H = np.array([[1,1]])
>>> H.T
array([[1],
       [1]])
```

Equivalently you can write `np.transpose(H)`. Notice this array has shape `(1,2)`, so it has two dimensions. The array `H = np.array([1,2])` has shape `(2,)`. It only has one dimension. To swap the dimensions (transpose), you need at least two of them.

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation:

> numpy.matrix.transpose. Returns a view of the array with axes transposed. For a 1-D array, this has no effect. (To change between column and row vectors, first cast the 1-D array into a matrix object.)

Comment: When I use the following:    matrix('[1, 2; 3, 4]')    It says 'list' object is not callable

Comment: You have called a variable `matrix` and assigned a list to it. That is why `from numpy import *` is a bad idea.