# Why matrix shape is not 2 by 2 after element wise matrix multiplication?

Tags: python, numpy

In the following code I expect that the shape of s should be (2,2) but it is only 2. Why? If I convert b in two dimensional array it works fine. But how python handles arrays have shape(2,)? If I take its transpose shape should be (1,2) but it remains(2,) indicating that it still remains row even after taking transpose. Is it compulsory to convert b int 2 dimensional array to perform element wise matrix multiplication?

```
`v = np.arange(6).reshape(2,3)
for i in range(1):
    b =(v[:,i])
    c= b.T
    s = np.multiply(b,c)
    print(s)  #(2,)`
```

Comment: Transpose exchanges dimensions, it does not add any.  `(2,) => (2,)`, `(1,2) => (2,1)`.

Comment: Can you please elaborate it a bit more. transpose should convert rows into columns.riight? that's why I expect (1,2) shape after taking transpose.

Comment: Forget the words, row and column, and focus on the shape tuple.  What does `reverse the dimensions` mean?  Reread the docs.

Comment: *"But how python handles arrays have shape(2,)? If I take its transpose shape should be (1,2)"*.  That is not how the transpose operation works in NumPy.  If an array has shape (2, 1), then its transpose has shape (1, 2), as expected.  But an array with shape (2,) has no dimensions to swap.  The transpose operation on such an array is a "no op"; the result is the same array, with shape (2,).

Comment: You are not the first to be surprised by this.  With the right search terms, you will find many similar questions here on Stackoverlow.  For example, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5954603/transposing-a-numpy-array, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52024613/np-transpose-doesnt-return-transpose-of-matrix (so this question can be closed as a duplicate).